# ASP Net Core 7.0 SPA Configuration - does not load static files on sub URL paths

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, routes, single-page-application

I am trying to **configure Asp Net Core 7.0** to host **Vanilla JS SPA APP**. It seams to work when navigating to single paths, **but on sub paths**, **it does not load the static files folder containing the Views** and the **main.js** which is the client side routing for the JS SPA APP. It loads only **index.html** without the **main.js** and the **Views**, thus the app can't route to the **Home** **view** because the **main.js** file and the **"Home.js"** view are missing, actually the whole folder with the **static files** is not loaded.

I think that it is something to do with the Program.cs file and the configuration.

So what I am trying to do is to load the Home View when there is wrong path.

**Ex. On single path as http://localhost:5109/Login works**
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();



 
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();  
}
else
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

 
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// SPA
app.UseDefaultFiles();  
app.UseStaticFiles();  

 
app.UseRouting();

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");  
app.Run();
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the missing "/" efore the static

**Before:**

```
<script type="module" src="static/js/main.js"></script>
```

**Now:**

```
<script type="module" src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
```

**The whole index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>


<body>

    <div>
        <a href="/Register" class="barItem" data-link>Register</a>
        <a href="/Login" class="barItem" data-link>Log In</a>
        <a href="/" class="barItem" data-link>Home</a>
    </div>


    <!----Center - app - Content ------------------------>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
</body> 

</html>
```

**It works now on sub paths.**
[image]